# materializecss read radio button

Tags: jquery-ui, google-apps-script, materialize

New to materializecss, trying to read radio button and not having any luck.

```
<form class="main" id="sponsorform" novalidate="novalidate" style="max-width: 480px;margin: 40px auto;">
   :
  <div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s12">
        <p>Choose race to sponsor</p>
        <p>
          <input type="radio" name="race" id="wdf">
          <label for="wdf">Women's Distance Festival</label>
          </p>
        <p>
          <input type="radio" name="race" id="msm">
          <label for="msm">Market Street Mile</label>
          </p>
                  </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field col s6">
        <button class="waves-effect waves-light btn submit-btn" type="submit" onclick="nextOrSubmitPage(); return false;">Next</button>
      </div>   
    </div>
  </div>
```

When I click on one of the options, the circle gets highlighted but using chrome inspect I do not see any change to the dom.

And when I try to read I see either

```
$('input[name=race]:checked').val()
"on"
```

or I get an error `Cannot read property 'val' of null

Not sure what changes in between the two behaviors, though.`

Note: this is all within google apps script. Not sure if that is relevant or not.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, after some hacking around, I found the following seems to work

`$('input[name=race]:checked').attr('id')`

Not sure if there's a better way to do this, but as I said it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

This may solve your problem.

`$("input[name=group1]:checked").next().text();`